# javascript press key function

Tags: javascript, html

**I want to add my javascript a key press function because my script run automaticaly**

I want it when i press a specific key it will run and stop

**The JS will not run / run automaticaly until i press *"a"***

When I press *"a"* it will run;

When I press *"e"* it will stop.

Can you add it to my javascript, Thanks.

here is the code bellow:

```js
var currentpos = 0,
  alt = 1,
  curpos1 = 0,
  curpos2 = -1

function initialize() {
  startit()
}

function scrollwindow() {
  if (document.all)
    temp = document.body.scrollTop
  else
    temp = window.pageYOffset
  if (alt == 0)
    alt = 1
  else
    alt = 0
  if (alt == 0)
    curpos1 = temp
  else
    curpos2 = temp
  if (curpos1 != curpos2) {
    if (document.all)
      currentpos = document.body.scrollTop + 1
    else
      currentpos = window.pageYOffset + 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
  } else {
    currentpos = 0
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
  }
}

function startit() {
  setInterval("scrollwindow()", 10) // change the value for speed the bigger the slow
}

window.onload = initialize
```

```html
<header id="top"></header>
<main>
  <article>
    <!-- long form content here -->
  </article>
  <br>
  <h1 id="chapter-heading">My Plug-in Spirit Ring</h1>
  </br>
  <div class=mp3>
    <audio controls autoplay loop>
        <source src="bg.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:0; position: absolute; left: 20%; top: 10%">
    <img src="Cover.png" />
    <img src="1.png" />
    <img src="2.png" />
    <img src="3.png" />
    <img src="4.png" />
    <img src="Thanks.gif" />
  </div>
</main>
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Please tell us what are you trying to do/have. We won't read through your code and imagine. Kindly, add some explanations.

Comment: The 10 millisecond rate on your timer is likely to cause problems.  A value of 250 might work better or alternatively use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by creating a boolean value called "shouldScroll" and then using event listeners on your desired buttons to set the value of that variable. Then in your interval check to see if the boolean is true before calling your page scrolling function.

```js
var currentpos = 0,
  alt = 1,
  curpos1 = 0,
  curpos2 = -1
  
 
var shouldScroll = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'a'){
    event.preventDefault();
    shouldScroll = true;
  } 
  
  if(event.key === 'e'){
    event.preventDefault();
    shouldScroll = false;
  }
});


function initialize() {
  startit()
}

function scrollwindow() {
  if (document.all)
    temp = document.body.scrollTop
  else
    temp = window.pageYOffset
  if (alt == 0)
    alt = 1
  else
    alt = 0
  if (alt == 0)
    curpos1 = temp
  else
    curpos2 = temp
  if (curpos1 != curpos2) {
    if (document.all)
      currentpos = document.body.scrollTop + 1
    else
      currentpos = window.pageYOffset + 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
  } else {
    currentpos = 0
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
  }
}

function startit() {
  setInterval(()=> shouldScroll && scrollwindow(), 10) // change the value for speed the bigger the slow
}
window.onload = initialize
```

```css
main {
  height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<header id="top"></header>
<main>
  <article>
    <!-- long form content here -->
  </article>
  <br>
  <h1 id="chapter-heading">My Plug-in Spirit Ring</h1>
  </br>
  <div class=mp3>
    <audio controls autoplay loop>
        <source src="bg.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>

  <div style="font-size:0; position: absolute; left: 20%; top: 10%">
    <img src="Cover.png" />
    <img src="1.png" />
    <img src="2.png" />
    <img src="3.png" />
    <img src="4.png" />
    <img src="Thanks.gif" />
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped me the most.
Also bless all your family for helping people that in needed.

Answer (score 2):

add in javascript file

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log('key', e); // look at
    if (e.code === 'KeyA') { // it is possible so
      // todo
      console.log('press a')
    }
    if (e.key === 'e') { // it is possible and so
      // todo
    }
    console.log('press e')
  })
```

Comment: Note that the "keypress" event is deprecated.  See: [MDN keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event)

Comment: change it to keydown

Comment: up voted after code revisions.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this using jquery.

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
if(e.which==65) {
  // "a"
}
if(e.which==69) {
  // "e"
}
});
```

for any word keyword code visit this article
https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: event.which is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which

Comment: This solution also uses jQuery which wasn't specified in the question nor necessary.